# filter array elememts to add to listView

Tags: arrays, qt, loops, listview, qml

I am reading from my firebase database, which holds nested data in the following format which I want to add specific elements of to a listView;

```
group {
    subgroup {
        index[0]{
            name: "Tom"
            message: "hello"
        }
        index[1]{
            name: "Dave"
            message: "goodbye"
        }
        index[2]{
            name: "Katie"
            message: "morning"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is add the `name` and `message` property to a listView in my app, an array is created when my app is launched with data from firebase, so I need to check for the name property and add to the list view when applicable.

I have used for loops and image visibility to display markers on a calendar, would a similar approach of looping through the array be the best option to create the list? I do need to create the list on specific dates on the calendar with 1 or more username entry in the same method.

By looping using the following code in my console shows what i want. yet i am struggling to translate into my list model, If i am just adding the `name` the below code works, but adding both to my list isn't working. My code is;

```
var nameArr = (JSON.stringify(value))
var parseData = JSON.parse(nameArr);
    for(var index in parseData)
        console.log("nameParse: ", parseData[index].name, ":", "detailsParse: ", parseData[index].message)



        ListView {
            id:eventListView
            spacing: 4
            clip: true
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            model: ListModel {id: model }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                model.clear();
                var list = parseData;
                for(var i in list)
                    model.append({"name": list[i].name, "details": list[i].message});          

            }

    delegate: Label {
          id: nameLabel                  
          text: modelData.name
          }
          Label {
          id: timeLabel
          text: modelData.message
          }
      }
```

Comment: You've asked about _filtering_. What exactly do you want to filter? As for the data array, you can use `group.subgroup`  as a model to your view. and `modelData.name` as a data provider in a delegate. But all this is only taking into account the fact that you actually do not filter anything. Otherwise you have to loop the array and add the items dynamically to the model.

Comment: @folibis Thanks for the reply and apologies if I wasn't clear, I mean by filtering to only add the `name` to my listView and ignore other data in the array, I have set the array to the model as that contains the data of `{"name":"Dave", "message":"goodbye"},{...}` ect, then if I set the text to `modelData.name` I either a blank entry in the list for each in object with `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString` in my log, or entries containing the full data not just the name! I will play around with loops as I don't tend to get on with them very well but hopefully that will provide a solution!

Comment: @folibis I've been working with your answer, and as the model is created from nested JSON firebase data I have been toying with loops. by parsing then looping the data I am able to create a single list say, `name` but cannot add the `message` as a second element for a details line, I am updating my question with further code! I need the list to be created on specific user dates where one or more user has saved which i'll be moving onto after this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript array could be used as a data source in this way:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    property var group: {
        "subgroup":  [
            {
                "name": "Tom",
                "message": "hello"
            },
            {
                "name": "Dave",
                "message": "goodbye"
            },
            {
                "name": "Katie",
                "message": "morning"
            }
        ]
    }
    model: group.subgroup
    delegate: Text { text: modelData.name }
}
```